# Snowsql is not connecting

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Having an issue with snowsql
It says

> 250001 (08001): Failed to connect to DB. Verify the account name is correct: po08337.snowflakecomputing.com:443. 000403: HTTP 403: Forbidden

[image]

how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please update your question with the exact Snowsql command you are issuing. Obviously you should obfuscate any username/passwords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you forgot to include the **region** in your account URL, so it should be something like this:

```
<account>.<region>.snowflakecomputing.com
```

The only exception for not including the region is for accounts in AWS US WEST region.